# Uniform initialization of int*: how can it be forced?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, uniform-initialization

The following code doesn't compile with *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 6.3.0* (compiler flags are `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
int main()
{
    int* a = int*{}; // doesn't compile
    //       ^^^^ can't be parsed as a type
    (void)a;

    using PInt = int*;

    PInt b = PInt{}; // compiles successfully
    //       ^^^^ is parsed as a type
    (void)b;
}
```

Is it a way to force `int*{}` be interpreted by the compiler in the right way here (`typedef`ing of `int*` is one of such ways)?

Comment: Why waste time on this instead of just writing `int* a = nullptr;`?

Comment: Is there a compiler with which this does compile?

Comment: @tuple_cat I want to understand in what situations such syntax can be interpreted as the standard-compliant code.

Comment: @DaveRager No, I just thought that it can be done with some parenthesis inserted in the right places.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options.

One, which you already discovered, is a type alias:

```
using PInt = int*;
PInt a = PInt{};
```

The other is to avoid the completely pointless copy-initialisation:

```
int* a{};
PInt a{};
```

The best is to stop wasting time on this fool's errand, and initialise your pointer in a clear manner:

```
int* a = nullptr;
```

Of course, that doesn't help you if your question is *really* about creating a temporary for use in an expression, rather than a full declaration (it isn't clear); but then you have a simple C-style `(int*)nullptr` to play with.

The short answer, though, is **no** you cannot "force" a compiler to ignore C++'s grammar and instead use some other grammar.

Comment: My point was in the following: the similar code sample with `new` compiles successfully: `int** c = new int*{};`. So I thought the code without `new` could compile with some parenthesis in it.

Comment: And I think that `int* a{};` is more clear syntax than `int* a = nullptr;` because the first one is _uniform_.

Comment: @Constructor: How does it being _uniform_ make it clearer? The latter example literally spells out what is going on, which is what you want in a computer program's source code.

Comment: Uniform initialization has the great bonus: you can simply change the type and the meaning of initialization won't change (as usual of course).

Comment: Except this very question proves that that is nonsense, since for some types the program doesn't even compile

Answer (score 0):

First thought was to use compound literals like:

```
int* a = (int*){};
```

but as suggested it is a C99 feature that exists in gcc and clang c++ compilers as an extension.

Better way could be to use `decltype(variable_name)` as a type to be uniformly initialized like:

```
int* a = decltype(a){};
```

This one successfully avoids `typedef` or `using` clause and does the job.

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zleJPiYTVe8C46ta)

Comment: Your code uses [_C99 compound literals_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) that are not C++ feature: [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vk0AI0RmsB5KdI32).

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
using identity = T;

int main()
{
    int* c = identity<int*>{};
    (void)c;
}
```

Comment: It it actually the same as the simple type alias.

Comment: @Constructor except you don't have to create an alias for every type you want to do this with, and having to come up with a name for it. Which I assumed was your problem with type aliases.